# Send thousands of SMS with Twilio

Tags: javascript, node.js, sms, twilio

I would like to send ~50,000 SMS with Twilio, and I was just wondering if my requests are going to crash if I loop through a phone number array of this size. The fact is that Twilio only allows 1 message for each request, so I have to make 50,000 of them.

Is it possible to do it this way or do I have to find another way?
50,000 seems too much but I have no idea of how many requests I can do.

```
phoneNumbers.forEach(function(phNb)
{
    client.messages.create({
        body: msgCt,
        to: phNb,
        from: ourPhone
    })
    .then((msg) => {
        console.log(msg.sid);
    });
})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is your question here?

Comment: I want to know if my requests are going to perform correctly or if I need to do it another way because the SMS amount is too huge. (edited question)

Comment: This sounds more appropriate of a question for Twilio themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two factors here.

- You need to consider [Twilio Api usage Limits.](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183648-Sending-and-Receiving-Limitations-on-Calls-and-SMS-Messages)
- Performing 50.000 parallel http requests (actually your code do it) is not a good idea: you will have memory problems.

Twilio sms limits change based on source and destination.

You have two solution:

**Perform 50k http requests sequentially**

```
    phoneNumbers.forEach(async function(phNb){
      try {
        let m = await client.messages.create({
          body: msgCt,
          to: phNb,
          from: ourPhone
        })
        console.log(a)
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
      } 
    })
```

**Perform 50k http requests concurrently with concurrency level**

This is quite easy to do with the awesome bluebird sugar functions. Anyway, the twilio package uses native promise. You can use async module with [mapLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapLimit) method for this purpose

Comment: I contacted the Twilio team to learn more about it. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Bad news, guys. This code does not satisfy the idea of sequentially requests. It just starts multiple asynchronous calls and immediately goes further. `forEach`  is not suitable here!

Comment: I updated my answer to provide working async/await sample.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

### API Limits

First up, a quick note on our limits. With a single number, Twilio has a limit of sending one message per second. You can increase that by adding more numbers, so 10 numbers will be able to send 10 messages per second. [A short code can send 100 messages per second.](https://www.twilio.com/sms/short-codes).

[We also recommend that you don't send more than 200 messages on any one long code per day.](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/us)

Either way I recommend using a [messaging service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages-copilot#create-a-messaging-service) to send messages like this.

Finally, you are also limited to 100 concurrent API requests. It's good to see other answers here talking about making requests sequentially rather than asynchronously as that will eat up the memory on your server as well as start to find requests are turned down by Twilio.

## Passthrough API

We now have an API that allows you to send more than one message with a single API call. It's known as the [passthrough API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/notifications#sending-to-bindings-in-the-notification-request), as it lets you pass many numbers through to the [Notify service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/notifications). You need to turn your numbers into "bindings" and send them via a Notify service, which also uses a messaging service for number pooling.

[The code looks a bit like this:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/notifications?code-sample=code-send-a-notification-with-bindings-in-request&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x)

```
const Twilio = require('twilio');    
const client = new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
const service = client.notify.services('ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

service.notifications
  .create({
    toBinding: [
      JSON.stringify({
        binding_type: 'sms',
        address: '+15555555555',
      }),
      JSON.stringify({
        binding_type: 'facebook-messenger',
        address: '123456789123',
      }),
    ],
    body: 'Hello Bob',
  })
  .then(notification => {
    console.log(notification);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

The only drawbacks in your situation is that every message needs to be the same and the request needs to be less than 1 megabyte in size. We've found that typically means about 10,000 numbers, so you might need to break up your list into 5 API calls.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will try this today.

Comment: Also @philnash, dont most carriers limit SMS to 1000 a day? per number?

Comment: Our guidelines recommend you don't send more than 200 per number per day as much higher than that means you run the risk of the carriers blocking the number. This is why, when sending significant numbers of messages in one day, a short code might be a good idea as their rates are higher.

Comment: I tried the notify service and it's working well. But of course it's a better idea if we could send 50,000 SMS with a short code. Because even if we use 10 long code numbers it should be very long. Thank you for your help

Comment: You can use a short code, you'd just need to purchase it from Twilio. Check out [the details on short codes here](https://www.twilio.com/sms/short-codes).

Comment: What if you want to send different messages? Should the Messaging Service be used instead?

Comment: If you want to send different messages to a lot of numbers, then Notify is not the way forward. You should use a messaging service that can spread messages out over numbers, but you will need to write your own loop to send the messages.

Comment: You are a legend. The code that is shown on Twilio Docs is incorrect and does not JSON.stringify each record, instead it surrounds all numbers together and was not working. Thank you tons

Answer (score 1):

You send your requests asynchronous due to non-blocking forEach body calls, I guess it's fastest for the Client. But the question is: does Twilio allow such a load from a single source? it needs to be tested... And if no, you should build some kind of requests queue, e.g. promise based, something like

```
function sendSync(index = 0) {
  if(index === phoneNumbers.length) {
    return;
  }
  client.messages.create({
      body: msgCt,
      to: phoneNumbers[index],
      from: ourPhone
  })
  .then(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg.sid);
      sendSync(index + 1);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
}

sendSync();
```

Or if you like async/await –

```
async function sendSync() {
  for (let phNb of phoneNumbers) {
    try {
      let msg = await client.messages.create({
        body: msgCt,
        to: phNb,
        from: ourPhone
      });
      console.log(msg);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } 
  })
}

sendSync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check that.

Comment: @Koko Good luck!