# What's the maximum recommended number of SMS that can be send from one number?

Tags: java, sms, twilio, twilio-api

Consider following scenario where I have a SMS batch that sends 50k SMS within an hour. I process my outgoing messages with Twilio Messaging Service that is build from 20 numbers at the moment.

I noticed recently that the outgoing messages are queued for a bit (according to the Twilio Console), which I think is related to limited number of phones that I wired to my Messaging Service.

So, I'd like to ask:

(1) what should be reasonable number of phone numbers to process such a SMS batch?

(2) is there any limitation for a number that prevents spamming?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718709/send-thousands-of-sms-with-twilio?rq=1 for good info on this topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send thousands of SMS with Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718709/send-thousands-of-sms-with-twilio)